# Motherboard or Power Supply issue? Funky boot up on Desktop

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown, temperature

My desktop computer is malfunctioning during starting up. I turn it on, and after about 3 seconds it turns off for a second then starts back up again. It does this process mutliple times before it starts up for real, and brings me to windows. Also, very rarely, but sometimes my computer randomly shuts down. This is not a temperature, because I monitor the temperature very closely and this happens when I am on a web browser, not gaming.

I'm using 16g ram with an Nvidia Titan V, Ryzen 1800x. All of that in a mini-itx case. The motherboard I am using is the Asrock Fatal1ty X370 Mini-ITX board.

https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Gaming-ITXac/index.asp

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Ken, have you tried running memory diagnostics on your RAM?

Comment: Is the mains lead plugged in securely? Are there any crackling sounds from the area of the PSU?

Comment: This actually sounds like "double-POSTing" behavior. Do you unplug or switch off a plug strip when you turn off the computer? Have you checked asrock for any BIOS updates?

Comment: all leads plugged in securely, and no, the power strip is never turned off.

Comment: Does the startup problem occur with a minimal set of components attached to the M/B? So, just one stick of RAM and no disk drives. And a different video card, if you have one available.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like a fault in your PSU - possibly a bad cap which is common, which is gradually charging - through multiple boots and the slightly lower stress of "warm" (as in components partially charged / disks spinning - not partial ) boot.

I disagree that this is double posting behaviour, as it's looking more then once.

Comment: I agree, it can be that. Or it is also possible, that your PSU is running on it's limits. What's the model of your PSU?

Comment: I tried two different platinum power supplies. I really doubt both of them are faulty. The ones I tried were almost top of the line, the http://www.thermaltake.com/Power_Supply/Toughpower_iRGB_Series_/Toughpower_iRGB_PLUS/C_00003141/Thermaltake_Toughpower_iRGB_PLUS_1050W_Platinum_TT_Premium_Edition/design.htm

Comment: Why was this not part of your question - indeed why did you even ask the question if you have tried multiple PSUs?